# How to search (case-sensitive) for files using Java glob pattern?

Tags: java, glob

I am checking the [getPathMatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher%28java.lang.String%29) method of [FileSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) class. The documentation of the method says:

> For both the glob and regex syntaxes, the matching details, such as
>   whether the matching is case sensitive, are implementation-dependent
>   and therefore not specified.

I tested this and came to know that by default it is case-insensitive. How to make it case-sensitive?

I am using JDK7u25 on Windows7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not case-insensitive by default. As the doc says, case sensitivity is implementation dependent.

And NTFS is *case preserving* but *case insensitive*. That is, a file named `README.txt` will keep its case (case preserving); but trying and finding it by the name `Readme.TXT`, say, *will* work (case insensitive).

This is not the case on Unix systems, whose filesystems *are* case sensitive.

Unfortunately, there is no way around that! Other than creating your own `Filesystem` implementation wrapping the default and make it case sensitive.

Here is an example of a VERY limited purpose `FileSystem` which will be able to generate a "case sensitive matching" of filename extensions:

```
public final class CaseSensitiveNTFSFileSystem
    extends FileSystem
{
    private static final Pattern MYSYNTAX = Pattern.compile("glob:\\*(\\..*)");

    private final FileSystem fs;

    // "fs" is the "genuine" FileSystem provided by the JVM
    public CaseSensitiveNTFSFileSystem(final FileSystem fs)
    {
        this.fs = fs;
    }

    @Override
    public PathMatcher getPathMatcher(final String syntaxAndPattern)
    {
        final Matcher matcher = MYSYNTAX.matcher(syntaxAndPattern);
        if (!matcher.matches())
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        final String suffix = matcher.group(1);
        final PathMatcher orig = fs.getPathMatcher(syntaxAndPattern);

        return new PathMatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(final Path path)
            {
                return orig.matches(path)
                    && path.getFileName().endsWith(suffix);
            }
        };
    }

    // Delegate all other methods of FileSystem to "fs"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can you please help me how to create own Filsystem implementation and make it case sensitive by giving an example?

Comment: Uhwell, this is not going to be simple at all. You'll have to use composition and interpret the pattern... Far from being easy.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to use Pattern and Matcher, as I want to keep regex and glob separate in my functionality. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Here I only use a pattern to recognize a syntax for a `PathMatcher`. A limited subset, of course! But this illustrates how this can be done.