# Is there a way to make doxygen case sensitive to only specific titles?

Tags: html, linux, configuration, doxygen

I recently posted this question:
[Doxygen configuration on Linux to ignore case sensitivity when put onto windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735238/doxygen-configuration-on-linux-to-ignore-case-sensitivity-when-put-onto-windows)

The above posted was basically asking if there was a way to make Doxygen case sensitive so that when I use it, similar file titles such as CONE and cone get identified as different files and are saved as such.

Doxygen gave me a great answer by saying I should set CASE_SENSE_NAMES to "NO." It worked but unfortunately I realized it changed every capital letter in every title. Unfortunately i have over 3000 cases where this occurs and I can't go through and change the items linking to them.

So my main question is, is there a way to make doxygen case sensitive (similar to above) for only specific files. If i only wanted to it make the change to CONE and cone, how could I incorporate that in?

I love doxygen and have been using it for a long time! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search (case-sensitive) for files using Java glob pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545098/how-to-search-case-sensitive-for-files-using-java-glob-pattern)